# Fit exponential function with potentially negative base in R using mle

Tags: r, mle

This is probably a silly question but here goes:
I want to fit parameter "a" from x^a using mle in R.
When x>=0, I want the function to read:

```
x^a
```

When x<0, I want however the function to change into

```
-(-x)^a
```

.
A simple "if-else" specification in the code does not work. 
For example:

```
Q<-function(r){
    if(r>=0){r^a}
    else{-(-r)^a}
  }
```

The program returns the following warning:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Has anyone else encountered a similar challenge? At face value this seems like a problem similar to a piecewise regression...But how would one implement this in a mle function? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you use `ifelse()` or `if() {} else {}`? Please show the code that actually produced the error. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: As a first step I was looking for a simple tip to a possibly quite straight-forward topic. Ultimately, I want to use the mle function in R to fit a parameter of a function whose functional form changes according to the value of its argument.

Comment: Use `Q<-function(r) ifelse(r>=0, r^a, -(-r)^a)`. Your function should be properly vectorized.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, this syntax seems to have done the trick!